# Python While loop is running several times more than it should

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

While Loop running extra several steps

Condition Outside While is False but inside while it becomes True,
how does the same variable start has different values inside and outside while loop??

Below is the python code I am executing

```
END = 10
STEP = 3
def generate(start , last ):
    print ("START:%s , END: %s " %(start, last))
    if start > END:
        print ("Should have stopped,", start, END)
    while (start < END):
        print (start < END, start , END)
        start = last
        last = last +STEP
        print("NEXT---start:%s Stop : %s " % (start, last))
        generate(start = start, last=last )
 generate(0, STEP)
```

**Output**

This is the print output of above code .

```
START:0 , END: 3 
     True 0 10
    NEXT---start:3 Stop : 6 
    START:3 , END: 6 
    True 3 10
    NEXT---start:6 Stop : 9 
    START:6 , END: 9 
    True 6 10
    NEXT---start:9 Stop : 12 
    START:9 , END: 12 
    True 9 10
    NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
    START:12 , END: 15 
    Should have stopped, 12 10
    True 9 10
    NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
    START:12 , END: 15 
    Should have stopped, 12 10
    True 6 10
    NEXT---start:9 Stop : 12 
    START:9 , END: 12 
    True 9 10
    NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
    START:12 , END: 15 
    Should have stopped, 12 10
    True 9 10
NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
START:12 , END: 15 
Should have stopped, 12 10
True 3 10
NEXT---start:6 Stop : 9 
START:6 , END: 9 
True 6 10
NEXT---start:9 Stop : 12 
START:9 , END: 12 
True 9 10
NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
START:12 , END: 15 
Should have stopped, 12 10
True 9 10
NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
START:12 , END: 15 
Should have stopped, 12 10
True 6 10
NEXT---start:9 Stop : 12 
START:9 , END: 12 
True 9 10
NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
START:12 , END: 15 
Should have stopped, 12 10
True 9 10
NEXT---start:12 Stop : 15 
START:12 , END: 15 
Should have stopped, 12 10
```

It stops here only

Comment: You recursively call this function at the end of while loop. Try to use debugging line by line to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep calling till condition is True but it calls even if condition is not True.

Comment: You are logging the value of `last`, not `END` in your first `print` statement. Notice that `last` is incremented by `STEP` at each iteration, so with a starting value of `last == STEP == 3`, you cannot expect `last` to equal `10` (`END`) at any point. Your code does stop when `start > END` (`12 > 10`), but `END != last` (`10 != 15`). Either try to put `breakpoint()` after your first print statement and use the `pdb` debugger or change that print statement to `print ("START:%s, LAST:%s, END: %s " %(start, last, END))` to see what is going on. Besides, it is best to avoid recursion here.